# Left Join Linq Table From Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I'm still getting my head around C# Linq and I've come across a problem I can't seem to solve.

I had an SQL query where one part of it LEFT JOINED one table on values from two other tables using an OR statement:

```
LEFT JOIN countries ON h.CCode = countries.CCode OR t.CCode = countries.CCode
```

I don't know how to replicate this in Linq?

I have some code in the query which gets the table but it's not LEFT Joined so returns  incorrect results

```
from dc in db.countries where dc.CCode == h.CCode || dc.CCode == t.CCode
```

I can't join the table directly using equals as there are two tables and it won't work.

Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: Did you try to google this question? There are tons of results, like this official one from Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: I've spent hours online Googling this problem and I haven't found anything that comes close to answering it. I know how to left Join a table but I just can't find out how to do it this way?

Comment: refer this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aba0fb67-d290-475c-a639-075424096b29/linq-joining-3-tables?forum=linqtosql) it may help you.